# XMLEncoder and PersistenceDelegate

Tags: java, xmlencoder

I'm trying to use `XMLEncoder` to write an object graph (tree in my case) to a file. However, one class contained in it is not actually a Java bean and I don't particularly like making its guts publicly accessible. It's accessed more like a list and has appropriate `add`/`remove` methods.

I've already written a custom `PersistenceDelegate` to deal with that. However, it seems that I have to add the `PersistenceDelegate` to the `XMLEncoder` instance manually.

Is there any way for `XMLEncoder` to pick it up on its own or do I really need to add it whenever I use an encoder to write a graph that *may* contain said class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging through our codebase I came across a `XMLEncodeFactory` class which allows one to register `PersistenceDelegates` for certain classes and handles creating `XMLEncoder` instances with those delegates pre-set. The code itself is very straightforward but I would have thought such a capability would be already offered by Java.

I was told this was created after conversation with the original developers of the `XMLEncoder` class and there apparently isn't a nicer alternative.